# LASSO regression coefficient values different from regular glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lasso

So I have done a LASSO regression, and the output is about 5 coefficients and an intercept. However, if I choose the same variables (I know I shouldn't do that) as the LASSO regression find, and input them into a regular `glm` binomial regression, well the coefficient values are not the same. Some are close, but some are a factor 10 off.

Is that perfectly normal, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. LASSO stands for "least absolute **shrinkage** and selection operator". The coefficients are shrunk towards zero as compared to nonpenalized regression such that performed by `glm`.

The effect of shrinkage, combined with selection, is to make the model less sensitive to the patterns in the data and thus reduce variance at the cost of some bias. According to the bias-variance trade-off, as long as variance reduction dominates the increase in squared bias, the mean squared error will be reduced.